# User-role based middleware return appropriate HTTP response status code

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a middleware for `admin` users:

```
let admin_middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.header('x-auth');

    User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
        if(!user || user._doc.user_type !== user_roles.admin)
            return Promise.reject();

        req.user = user;
        req.token = token;
        next();
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(401).send();
    })
};
```

The question is around this line of code:

```
if(!user || user._doc.user_type !== user_roles.admin)
        return Promise.reject();
```

When using the `admin_middleware` in `server.js` I catch the rejected promise :

```
.catch(e => {
    res.status(401).send();
})
```

which means that for both: user `not authorized` and `access forbidden I return the 401 status code.

I would like to return 403 in one case, and 401 in another. What would be the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: You can reject it with an error that has the status code you want, default to 401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments. You can reject with custom error like this:

```
class UnauthorizedError extends Error {}
class ForbiddenError extends Error {}

let admin_middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.header('x-auth');

  User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
    if (!user) return Promise.reject(new UnauthorizedError());
    if (user._doc.user_type !== user_roles.admin) return Promise.reject(new ForbiddenError());

    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch((e) => {
    if (e instanceof  UnauthorizedError) {
      res.status(401);
    } else if (e instanceof ForbiddenError) {
      res.status(403);
    } else {
      res.status(500);
    }
    res.send();
  })
};
```

Comment: Seems like you've feel into the trap of using Exceptions to handle application flow here.

Comment: A little bit... any suggestions?

Comment: I was also thinking about this implementation as I have no other ideas. Thank you very much!